# Hibernate envers 3.6 get all version from entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to recover all version from a entity, but my code all ways returns only 1 version, this is the way i'm doing it now.

```
    return AuditReaderFactory.get(super.getEntityManager())
            .createQuery()
            .forEntitiesAtRevision(BitacoraControl.class, bitacoraControlId.intValue())
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(bitacoraControlId))
            .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().asc())
            .getResultList()
            ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEntitiesAtRevision` retrieves an entity matching the conditions at a specific revision - hence you get at most one result.

You should probably use `forRevisionsOfEntity`, to get a list of revisions of a specific entity.

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine, the code looks like this now.            `return AuditReaderFactory.get(super.getEntityManager())
      .createQuery()
      .forRevisionsOfEntity(BitacoraControl.class,  true, true)
      .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(bitacoraControlId))
      .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().asc())
      .getResultList();`